# Como usar ponteiros no delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
if TMenuItem(fmPrincipal.FindComponent('teste')) <> nil then         
  if TMenuItem(fmPrincipal.FindComponent('teste')).Visible then
  ...
```

Procuro um item do menu e verifico se ele está visível. Porém meu código está crescendo e estou tendo que adicionar mais verificações se o item está habilitado etc.

Como eu poderia usar um ponteiro para apontar para esse objeto e usar o ponteiro a partir de então, sem precisar ficar fazendo o `FindComponent` toda hora?

Answer (score 3):

Atribuindo ele a uma variável por referência.
Dessa forma simplifica o acesso e quantidade de busca será extremamente reduzida.

```
var 
  mi: TMenuItem;
begin
  mi := TMenuItem(fmPrincipal.FindComponent('teste'));
  if mi <> nil then
  begin
    if mi.Visible then
    ...
    mi.Enabled:= ...
  end;
end;
```